# Probability of D given complement of B

Tags: probability

Question: 
A student goes to the library. Let events $B = \{\text{the student checks out a book}\}$ and $D = \{\text{the student checks out a DVD}\}$. Suppose that $P(B) = 0.40, P(D) = 0.30$ and $P(D|B) = 0.5$.

```
A.Find P(B′).
B.Find P(D AND B).
C.Find P(B|D).
D.Find P(D AND B′).
E.Find P(D|B′).



A.P(B′) = 0.60
B.P(D AND B) = P(D|B)P(B) = 0.20
C.P(B|D) = P(B AND D)P(D) = (0.20)(0.30) = 0.66
D.P(D AND B′) = P(D) - P(D AND B) = 0.30 - 0.20 = 0.10
E.P(D|B′) = P(D AND B′)P(B′) = (P(D) - P(D AND B))(0.60) = (0.10)(0.60) = 0.06
```

So I have all the answers for this question, and I understand them perfectly except for part E. I don't understand how the answer was found. If I'm finding the $P(D|B')$ I thought my set up would be:

$$P(D|B')=\frac{P(D)-P(D \text{ AND } B)}{1-P(B)}= \frac{0.30-0.20}{1-0.40}= .167$$

Is this set up wrong? Why is my supposed solution a different set up?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like their answer is wrong for E.

Recall that by the product rule
$$P(\bar BD) = P(D|\bar B)P(\bar B)$$
and hence
$$P(D|\bar B) = \frac{P(\bar B D)}{P(\bar B)}.$$

Further, recall that
$$P(D) = P(DB)+P(D\bar B),$$ which gives us that

$$P(D|\bar B) = \frac{P(\bar B D)}{P(\bar B)} = \frac{P(D)-P(DB)}{1-P(B)}$$
which is what you have, which I believe is correct.